# Why I can remove only some of the rows in my datatable table? (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using datatables.js script and I'm filling my table with data taken from json. Everything works pretty smooth, however there is one issue that I don't understand. Each row in my table has a `remove` link defined as:

```
$.each(json, function(i, v) {
   var row = table.row.add([v.number, v.id, v.price, v.date, '<a>remove</a>']);
   table.cells( { row : row.index(), column : 4 }).nodes().to$().find('a')
      .attr('href', '#')
      .addClass('show-details')
      .css('cursor', 'pointer')
      .data('id', v.hidden)
      .data('v', v)   
      .on('click', function() {
            var v = $(this).data('v');
            console.dir(v);
       row.remove();
            table.draw();           
      })
   table.draw();
})
```

And it works in some cases, but in some - it doesn't. I'm unable to remove all the rows one after another. There is always one left. What's going on here?

You can see this behavior in my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2wujw71x/15/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that everytime you delete a row by calling   `row.remove()`, it deletes the row by using index. Because of this, if you delete the rows randomly, the index would mess up. ( Check here for what I mean : http://jsfiddle.net/2wujw71x/16/ ).

The best way to delete the rows would be target the nearest `tr` element and then invoke `remove()` with `draw()`.

```
var table = $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
                responsive: true
        });   

var data = '[{"number":"1","id":"2","price":"100.70","date":"2015-10-18 03:00:00","hidden":"21"},{"number":"2","id":"2","price":"88.20","date":"2015-10-18 04:00:00","hidden":"22"},{"number":"3","id":"3","price":"120.70","date":"2015-10-18 07:00:00","hidden":"23"},{"number":"4","id":"4","price":"1021.70","date":"2015-10-18 01:00:00","hidden":"21"}]';

json = JSON.parse(data);

$.each(json, function(i, v) {
   var row = table.row.add([v.number, v.id, v.price, v.date, '<a>remove</a>']);
   table.cells( { row : row.index(), column : 4 }).nodes().to$().find('a')
      .attr('href', '#')
      .addClass('show-details')
      .css('cursor', 'pointer')
      .data('id', v.hidden)
      .data('v', v)   
      .on('click', function() {    
      var v = $(this).data('v');  
      table.row($(this).closest("tr").get(0)).remove().draw();
            console.dir(v);         
      })
   table.draw();
})
```

Fixed here : http://jsfiddle.net/2wujw71x/17/

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense now! Just one more question - is there a way of displaying an alert msg when the last row is deleted?